# Optimization EmberJS+ Phonegap +NFC +Geoposition

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, phonegap-plugins

I'm confused about the use `phonegap` and `EmberJS`, I generally use the following steps when building a phonegap app:

1. I include the `index.js` and init the app, from the index.html

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" >  app.initialize(); </script>
```

Now when I try to merge the phonegap and EmberJs I do the same that the step above, but I add the call to ember in the index.js, like:

```js
var app = 
{
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },
  onDeviceReady: function() 
  {
     window.App = Ember.Application.create({LOG_TRANSITIONS: true});
  },
  receivedEvent: function(id) {

  },
```

};

In this point I get the folliwing error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot use the same root element (body) multiple times in an Ember.Application
```

So, I create ember application without the common structure of phonegap , it's mean in the index.js I just put

```js
window.App = Ember.Application.create({LOG_TRANSITIONS: true});
```

And the index.html jus put the reference

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

It's work, but  I work with `NFC` + `geoposition`  and I see that it's work **ver very slow** (Compare if you only use phonegap) when I merge the `phonegap` and `EmberJs`

I use the following code inside of some controller to use a NFC+Geoposition and  maybe here it's the "trouble"

```js
nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
            function(nfcEvent)
            {
                var $this=self;
                var tag = nfcEvent.tag;
                var tagNFC = nfc.bytesToHexString( tag.id );
                var geo = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                    function(position)
                    {
                        var lt = position.coords.latitude;
                        var lg = position.coords.longitude;                         
                        //I use a tagNFC to send via ajax to call SOAP web service
                        //......
                    },
                    function(status){

                    },
                    function(error){

                    }
                );
            },
            function(status){

            },
            function(error){
                console.log("NFC reader failed to initializer: "+JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        );
```

So

1. What is the best way to init the app `phonegap` and app `EmberJS`?
2. What is the best way to use and NFC  + Geoposition phonegap plugins inside of controller of EmberJS?
3. What is the way to call nfc+ geoposition just one time?, because always I see that my application stop inside the nfc+geoposition method and generate a loop to reed tags nfc.
4. **Suggestions programming practices** for `phonegap` js and  `emberJS.`

Thanks.